Is there a safety concern using a 20 Amp circuit for a heater drawing 8.3 Amps?
I am installing a Cadet wall heater (240v, 2000w, 8.3a). My intention due to sustained high draw is as follows:
50ft run 12/2
Double pole 20a breaker
I recognize this may a bit of overkill and that I could get by with 14/2 and a double-pole 15A breaker.
Are there any hazards associated with this setup, other than cost?

Please see [ask] and take the [tour], then revise your title to ask a single, clear, specific question. Welcome.

Most code states what the minimum is allowed.  Your wallet states how larger you go(not going above connection size limits).  Most devices should be protected by the minimum breaker size needed, so 12 gauge is okay, 20 amp breaker not as good.

You seem to be assuming that those experts who established standards didn't consider this use case. That's mistaken reasoning. As long as you're under the 80% current draw rule of thumb there's no point in oversizing except for future-proofing. It doesn't add substantial safety.

Another thing to consider is the instructions for the heater: do they specify a particular breaker size? If so, you must follow the instructions to satisfy NEC.

Running wires well below their thermal limits is a cure for a lot of ills. A mistorqued connection is less likely to be troublesome, for instance.  But the reason I would run #12 is it works on all circuits.  While #14 is cheaper per foot, I don't lay enough Romex to justify the upfront cost of buying 2 more spools (14/2 and 14/3).

There are three reasons to consider installing a larger than needed circuit:

Voltage Drop - This is simply not a factor at 50 feet. Generally not a factor with 240V circuits until a couple hundred feet, though there are some exceptions. But not 50 feet. And this would be a reason to increase the wire size without increasing the circuit breaker size.
Continuous Use - This is the actual safety concern, but rather than rely on electricians to guess at it, code requires an 80% derate for continuous use such as these types of heaters. Which means that you can only provision 12A on a 15A circuit and 16A on a 20A circuit. But 8.3A is well below 12A, so that is not a concern here.
Future Expansion - This can be a concern. Is there any chance that you might want to upgrade to a larger heater in the future? Or run another heater for a nearby room from the same circuit? In that case having a 20A/12 AWG circuit lets you run another 8.7A. But actually you should check the specifications very carefully. It may be that the 2000W is based on 250V (manufacturers like round numbers that also make things look more powerful). If it actually uses exactly 8A at 240V (and you have 240V power) then a 20A circuit would allow another identical heater. A 15A circuit would obviously not allow another identical heater.

Note that unlike many other things, typical resistance heaters are designed to coexist on larger-than-necessary circuits. That is a big advantage when it comes to installing lots of small heaters - e.g., running one 20A/12 AWG circuit that splits to provide auxiliary heat for two back-to-back bathrooms (bathrooms are built that way for plumbing reasons) is likely cheaper than running two 15A/14 AWG circuits. So check the specs on the heater to make sure it doesn't have a max. circuit size (overcurrent protection) of 15A. If that isn't a problem and there is any reasonable chance of future expansion then 20A/12 AWG is quite reasonable.

One other consideration: Will anything else be plugged into the same circuit and used at the same time, and will the combination push you over the rated limits? I had one apartment where if I plugged the stereo and the vacuum into the same outlet it would pretty reliably pop the 15A breaker.

@keshlam Extremely unlikely, because in the US scheme, for better or worse, 240V circuits are almost entirely limited to special circuits for specific devices - heaters like this one, clothes dryer, water heater, HVAC, oven, cooktop, EVSE, etc. Extremely rare to find receptacles used for 240V devices except dedicated receptacles as above (and most of those are hardwired most of the time anyway) with the exception of someone who sets up either a home server farm (e.g., "mining") or a heavy-duty workshop. In those cases however, NEC limits receptacles only to circuits with <50% of max. load

hardwired, so a heater circuit normally wouldn't have that much excess to use for general purpose receptacles anyway. In other areas where everything is 240V (or similar) it is a different story.

"Voltage drop" is not a reason to reason to upsize a branch circuit. It can be a reason to upsize wire, leaving circuit size alone.
